# Parsing atom/rss feed containing multiple <link> tags with Haml on RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, rss, haml

So, firstly, here's an Atom feed snippet which I am trying to parse:

```
// http://somelink.com/atom   
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <entry>
        <title>Title Here</title>
        <link href="http://somelink.com/link1&amp;amp;ref=rss" rel="alternate" />
        <link href="http://somelink.com/link2&amp;amp;ref=rss" rel="tag:somelink.com/apply_url"/>
    ...
    </entry>
```

I pull the Atom feed like so,

```
// In controller index method
@rss = SimpleRSS.parse open('http://somelink.com/atom')
```

Then I output the response in the view, which I am writing using Haml, as follows:

```
- @rss.entries.each do |item|
  .title-div
    = item.title
  .title-link
    = item.link //outputs the first link
```

I could run a second loop for the links but is there a way to get the second link without it? Like reading the "rel" attribute and outputting the correct link? How do I do this in Haml/Rails?

EDIT: The gem i am using: http://simple-rss.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that gem, but have you tried `item.links` to see if each item provides a collection of links?

Comment: aah no...that outputs nothing

Answer (score 0):

I have never used SimpleRSS but maybe you could give [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) or [Hpricot](http://hpricot.com/) a try? You can than run an XPath query to only select the link with the right attribute. An example with Nokogiri:

```
atom_doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("http://www.example.com/atom.xml"))
atom_doc.xpath("/xmlns:feed/xmlns:entry/xmlns:link[@rel='tag:somelink.com/apply_url']")
```

Don't forget the namespaces if you are parsing an Atom feed.